# Defining the structure of data that is composed of several values

Tags: mysql, database-design

By this question I mean something like this:

For example a student has a student ID of 31080014. This student ID is a combination of information with the breakdown as follow

- 3 -> Information Technology Department
- 1 -> Software Engineering Study Program
- 08 -> Year entering, 08 means 2008
- 0014 -> 14th student when the name is ordered from A to Z. Ordering is done after the final admission wave has been completed. Additional student, like if a student transfers in the middle of the semester will be given the next available number. So for example if there are 200 students, the 201th student (the transfer student) will be given the Student ID of 31080201 regardless of his name.

What is the best practice to structure this? Should I just make one column called *StudentID* with type of `varchar`? Which means that if I have a program that filters *Student* by their *Department*, then my query would have to use `LIKE 3%` and be indexed.

Or should I arrange them into separate columns? Please also explain why one is the better practice than the other.

Comment: What you call an ID i'd call it a code, because it *encodes* information. It is not an arbitrary number. You have many problems with this approach... such as, what happens when *Aaron* joins the class one month late because he moved from somewhere else? Do you change the 0014 to 0015 for your student, because someone got into the list first? This all goes radically against *normalization*, and most people would consider it *bad practice*. That is, no possible *best practice* for this. I've done some encodings similar to this on *barcodes*, and even those have caused me problems.

Comment: Instead of "bad practice", I would call it "old fashioned" or "BCE" ("Before Computer Era").